# Custom calculated shipping costs based on shipping class in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, checkout

After updating Woocommerce to the latest version 3.5.7 last night, the checkout is freezing if country is switched from US to Canada on the checkout page. If we go back to the cart page, an error is shown. The error details are at the end of this question. What could be causing this? I have also copied the piece of code below that's leading to this error. Specifically, the line `$label = $method->get_label();`, but I don't see any issues with this.

**What I already tested:**

1- I first thought using braces on shipping labels is breaking but that's not the issue, already tested on a demo site. 

2- This only happens when specific shipping method is present in the cart, doesn't happen for other shipping methods as highlighted by the screen cast video below.

---

**Edit #1:**

I talked with Woocommerce support and they said we are using old template versions so we have to update them. I am now updating the templates but also suspect that's not going to resolve the issue. Any thoughts?

**Screen recording:**
 https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqfVoTZckd

**Code inside `cart-shipping.php` that's causing the issue:**

```
foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?> 
                    <li>
                        <?php
                            $a = (int)$method->cost;
                            $b = $method->id;
                            $label = $method->get_label(); /* this line is causing the error but I don't see any issue with it */
                            if ($a === 0 && $b != "legacy_local_pickup"):
                                printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" %4$s />
                                <label for="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s">Standard (Ships in 10-12 work days): <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">Free</span></label>',
                                $index, sanitize_title( $method->id ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ) );
                            elseif ($b == "legacy_local_pickup"):
                                printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" %4$s />
                                <label for="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s">%5$s</label>',
                                $index, sanitize_title( $method->id ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ), $label );    
                            else:
                                printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" %4$s />
                                <label for="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s">%5$s</label>',
                                $index, sanitize_title( $method->id ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ), wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) );   
                            endif;

                            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', $method, $index );
                        ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach;
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::get_label() in .../themes/genesis-sample/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php:35 Stack trace: #0 .../plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(211): include() #1 .../plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php(233): wc_get_template('cart/cart-shipp...', Array) #2 .../plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php(48): wc_cart_totals_shipping_html() #3 .../plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(211): include('...') #4 .../plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(1922): wc_get_template('cart/cart-total...') #5 .../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): woocommerce_cart_totals('') in .../themes/genesis-sample/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php on line 35
```

---

**Edit #2:**

After testing on a staging site, I have found the real cause. Here's the piece of code creating problems. The problem is, `$method_id5` is only available for US and not for Canada, so when customer switches to Canada, this piece of code bugs out. For Canada, the available shipping method is `$method_id6 = 'flat_rate:6';`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_shipping_method_rate_based_on_shipping_class_2', 11, 2 );

function change_shipping_method_rate_based_on_shipping_class_2( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $class = array(206);

    // HERE define the shipping method to change rates for
    $method_id5 = 'flat_rate:5';

    // Checking in cart items
    $found = false;
    $item_price = $item_qty = $rush_fee = 0;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $item_shipping_class_id = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();


        if( in_array( $item_shipping_class_id, $class ) ){
            $found = true;  // Target shipping class found
            $item_price += $cart_item['data']->get_price(); // Sum line item prices that have target shipping class
            $item_qty += $cart_item['quantity']; // Sum line item prices that have target shipping class
            $item_total = $item_price * $item_qty;
            $rush_fee = $item_total * 0.2;
        } 
    }

    if( $found ) {
        if( $item_total > 0 && $item_total < 200 ) {
            if($rush_fee < 25) {
                $rates[$method_id5]->cost = 25 + 18.99;
            } else {
                $rates[$method_id5]->cost = $rush_fee + 18.99;
            }
        }
        elseif ( $item_total > 200 ) {
            if($rush_fee < 25) {
                $rates[$method_id5]->cost = 25;
            } else {
                $rates[$method_id5]->cost = $rush_fee;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update #1:** *(Based on your 2nd Edit)*

Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_rates_based_on_shipping_class', 11, 2 );
function custom_shipping_rates_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $class = array(206);

    // HERE define the shipping method to change rates for
    $shipping_rate_ids = array('flat_rate:5', 'flat_rate:6')

    // Initialising
    $found = false;
    $item_price = $item_qty = $rush_fee = $item_total = 0;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $item_shipping_class_id = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();

        if( in_array( $item_shipping_class_id, $class ) ){
            $item_price += $cart_item['data']->get_price(); // Sum line item prices that have target shipping class
            $item_qty += $cart_item['quantity']; // Sum line item prices that have target shipping class
            $item_total = $item_price * $item_qty;
            $rush_fee = $item_total * 0.2;
            $found = true;  // Target shipping class found
        } 
    }

    if( $found ) {
        // Loop through shipping rates
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if( in_array($rate_key, $shipping_rate_ids) ) {
                if( $item_total > 0 && $item_total < 200 ) {
                    if($rush_fee < 25) {
                        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 25 + 18.99;
                    } else {
                        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rush_fee + 18.99;
                    }
                }
                elseif ( $item_total > 200 ) {
                    if($rush_fee < 25) {
                        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 25;
                    } else {
                        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rush_fee;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:** *(required)*
>
> 1. This code is already saved on your active theme's function.php file.
> 2. The cart is empty
> 3. In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save.

---

**Initial answer.**

As `$method` is a `stdClass` instance Object and not a `WC_Shipping_Rate` instance Object, the method `get_label()` is not defined for it *(doesn't exist)*. **Instead you can use the property `label`.**

So you just need to replace in the template:

```
$label = $method->get_label();
```

By

```
$label = $method->label;
```

This should stop this error and solve your issue.

Comment: it still gives the error...however now the file has changed ~Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::get_label() in .../plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php:345~

Comment: @DanishMuneer That is another issue, something else is making trouble: Now this occurs in the Woocommerce core files. You should try to get back woocommerce default templates (keeping yours in a renamed folder) to see what happen. Then you will make step by step the necessary changes to those templates, testing your code all the time.

Comment: You need to read the error unti the end… the guilty seems to be cart-shipping.php template…

Comment: It looks like something else is causing this...I have used braces () and a dash - in shipping method title. Can this somehow break the function? I am currently creating a staging site, it'll help me start testing and updating the templates.

Comment: @DanishMuneer Updated…